# Everytime I open my app, my database is created again and again

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am populating my SQLite database from a web service response. The first the app is run, the application is displaying the ListView correctly. The issue I am having is when I close the app and open it again, the database is just creating the same table and not overriding the data. So in return, my database keeps generating the same rows over and over one after another. So a response with 8 rows starts to become 16, 24, etc.

I have tried changing the DATABASE_VERSION number to force onUpgrade but that didn't haven't any results.

Database Class

```
public class EmployeeDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "OneTeam";
    private static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEE = "employees";
    //Employee table columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "Employee_number";
    private static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "First_name";
    private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "Last_name";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE = "Phone_mobile";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE = "Phone_office";
    private static final String KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE = "Payroll_title";
    private static final String KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS = "Has_direct_reports";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String KEY_COST_CENTER = "Cost_center_id";
    private static final String KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE = "ThumbnailData";
    private final static String DB_CLIENTS_ID = "_id";

    public EmployeeDBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
                + DB_CLIENTS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + KEY_ID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_COST_CENTER + " TEXT"
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //drop old table if existence
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE);
        //Create table again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    //Add new employee
    public boolean addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, employee.getEmployee_number());
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
        values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
        values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());
        //Inserting Row
        database.replace(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values);
        database.close();
        return true;
    }
    //Get single employee
    public Employee getEmployee(int employeeNumber) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Employee employee = null;    
        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, new String[]{
                        KEY_ID, KEY_FIRST_NAME, KEY_LAST_NAME, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE,
                        KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_COST_CENTER, KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(employeeNumber)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                employee = new Employee(cursor.getString(0),
                        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                        cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),
                        cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12),
                        cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(14), cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16),
                        cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19), cursor.getString(20),
                        cursor.getString(21), cursor.getString(22), cursor.getString(23), cursor.getString(24),
                        cursor.getString(24), cursor.getString(25), cursor.getString(26));
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        return employee;    
    }
    //Get All Employees
    public ArrayList<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Select all query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        //looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setEmployee_number(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                employee.setFirst_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRST_NAME)));
                employee.setLast_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LAST_NAME)));
                employee.setPhone_office(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE)));
                employee.setPhone_mobile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE)));
                employee.setHas_direct_reports(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS)));
                employee.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
                employee.setCost_center_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_COST_CENTER)));
                employee.setPayroll_title(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE)));
                employee.setThumbnailData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        //return employees list
        return employeeList;
    }

    //Get Employee Count
    public int getEmployeeCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    // Updating single employee
    public int updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
        values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
        values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());
        return database.update(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(employee.getEmployee_number())});
    }

    //Delete single employee
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(employee.getEmployee_number())});
        database.close();
    }

    //delete row
    public void delete(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        if (db == null) {
            return;
        }
        db.delete(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, "Employee+number = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Main Activity where the DB is created and populated with employees arraylist

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    private int mStartingEmployeeID = "startingNumber";
    private String table = "employees";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getXMLData();
        //GUI for seeing android SQLite Database in Chrome Dev Tools
        Stetho.InitializerBuilder inBuilder = Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);
        inBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this));
        Stetho.Initializer in = inBuilder.build();
        Stetho.initialize(in);
    }

    public void getXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);
                for (Employee e : employees) {
                     dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        displayTopList();
                        displayBottomList();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    public void displayTopList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mTopListCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID, null);
        ListView mTopListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mTopList);
        TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(this, mTopListCursor);
        mTopListView.setAdapter(topAdapter);
    }
    public void displayBottomList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mBottomListCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + "!=" + mStartingEmployeeID, null);
        ListView mBottomListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mDirectReportList);
        BottomListViewAdapter bottomAdapter = new BottomListViewAdapter(this, mBottomListCursor);
        mBottomListView.setAdapter(bottomAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide evidence of your claim that the database and table are recreated every time the app starts.

Comment: Every time you open your app , you execute your request and insert records so instead keep a `flag` in `Sharedpreference` or your can also query your `database` to check if the records exists or not

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to populate the database once when it is created? Or do you want to sync data with an online service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen from your code its behaving the correct way as per my understanding.

> your problem is due to this line in your code :
>           '
>
> //Inserting Row
>
> ```
>     database.replace(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values);
> ```

As this line would create a new record if doesn't find a matching record in the table. Also did you try to find how the matching of records is done, I think its dependent on primary key which your are not providing.

If you need to update or sync your local data with server, do :

1. Either delete the previous data before inserting the new.(will be
   best for you according to me.) You can use triggers for that.
2. Use update query for updating records in DB.
3. If using replace API then please insert primary_key value in the content values, so that you can get correct functionality.

This is for all my friends, if they face a similar problem.Taking clue from @Adam:

4. using unique key constraint, as he implemented. See comments for more info.

Comment: I added "UNIQUE(" + KEY_ID + ")" to my onCreate method in the EmployeeDBHandler to make the employeeID the unique ID and now it does not generate the response over and over everytime I close and open the app. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The issue I am having is when I close the app and open it again, the database is just creating the same table and not overriding the data.

This is not true. The database and table are created only once when you start the app for the first time. However, you call `getXmlData()` every time that the app starts. This appears to fetch the data from a web service and insert it into the database. So you see data duplicated every time you run the app.

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, so here are two suggestions:

1. If you want to pull data from the web when the database is created, then you should move the `getXmlData()` method to `EmployeeDBHandler` and call it from `onCreate()` in that class.
2. If you are sharing data with a web service, then you need to add more sophisticated logic to keep track of which data has been downloaded already. One way to do this is to add an item to the XML which can be updated to indicate that the data has already been downloaded.

Comment: I want to hit the service everytime the application is open for updates as this web service usually is changed once a day whether they have removed a person or added a person. I can show Stetho when I first install the application, it has just the rows that the web service shows now, then if I close the app and run it again, it just added the same response to the database.

Comment: @AdamGardner you will need to do option 2 from my answer and determine which rows have already been added so that you do not add them twice like you are right now.

Comment: I'm not sending any data back, just grabbing data from the service to make sure I have the most updated version of the response.

Comment: @AdamGardner you can just drop the table and rebuild it if you want